# Is it possible to build short proofs of arbitrary computations over a big list?

Tags: hash-tree

With the use of Merkle Trees, you can prove the presence of an element of a very big list, with an amount of information logarithmic in the size of the whole tree. Merkle proofs, thus, probabilistically confirm the result of this specific fold:

```
isMember :: ∀ t . List t -> Bool
isMember e = foldr (\ h t -> h == e || t) False
```

My question is if the same result can be extended to arbitrary folds; or, in other words, is it possible to prove arbitrary computations about a big list using some clever trick similar to Merkle Trees?

Specifically, I want to store a huge dataset (>20 GB) on several computers, and then I want any of those nodes to make arbitrary claims about that dataset (like: `the max element is 198500461354!`), in such a way that other nodes can verify that claim is true without having to run `max` over the whole dataset themselves.

Comment: You can use libsnark, a compiler that can run C programs and produce a 288-byte proof of the computation. https://github.com/scipr-lab/libsnark

Answer (score 2):

*Merkle aggregation* can help you compute aggregation functions over the leaf data in a Merkle tree.

The technique is described in detail in Crosby & Wallach's paper on *history trees* [[1]](http://static.usenix.org/legacy/events/sec09/tech/full_papers/crosby.pdf), an append-only Merkle tree. Merkle aggregation can be used to **provably** compute things like $\max(\cdot,\cdot)$ functions over all leafs.

The idea is quite straightforward.
Each node can have an *attribute* and there's an *aggregator function* $\alpha(l, r)$ which takes the attributes from the two children and returns the parent's attribute. For example, the aggregator function can be $\max(\cdot,\cdot)$.

By recursively applying $\alpha(\cdot,\cdot)$ starting with the leafs, attributes can be computed or *aggregated* for all nodes in the tree, all the way up to the root. Furthermore, the computed attributes are hashed in the Merkle tree. Specifically, a node's hash is no longer just $H(h_l, h_r)$ but $H(h_l, a, h_r)$, where $h_l,h_r$ denote the left and right child hashes and $a$ denotes the aggregated attribute computed via $\alpha(l,r)$.

Including the attributes in the Merkle hashing enables a prover to convince a verifier that the aggregation was performed correctly. Of course, the Merkle proof is a bit different now. Specifically, a Merkle path from a leaf to the root consists not just of the hashes along the sibling path, but also of the attributes along the path **and** the sibling path, so as to verify the aggregation.

Hope this helps!

#### References

[1] *["Efficient Data Structures for Tamper-Evident Logging"](http://static.usenix.org/legacy/events/sec09/tech/full_papers/crosby.pdf)*, by Scott A. Crosby, and Dan S. Wallach